# cygwin newbie compiling and running c program files

Tags: cygwin

I just installed cygwin, latest version. wanted to compile and run a simple file. when i open cygwin terminal and type any of the commands :gcc,cc,g++ it says command not found. what am I missing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `gcc`, `cc`, and `g++` commands.

Not all packages are installed by default.  You need to run `setup.exe` again and select `gcc` and `gcc-g++` for installation.  You'll find them under the `Devel` (development) category.